# Book with kids with odd names and physical traits

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book about 10 years ago after I borrowed it from the Teen/YA section of the library.

- A teenage boy moves (possibly to Scotland? That’s ringing a bell) and meets a girl.
- They discover a facility locally where some children live. The book focuses on 3 or 4 children; I don’t know if they are the only ones there.
- They have odd names and bizarre physical traits. IIRC, one has no eyes, and one has wings.
- They have made up words to replace things in our language.
- The doctors who look after them make them watch a lot of documentaries.
- The boy and girl decide they are going to break the children out.

Comment: This is ringing a bell with me (not sure why) but I have a memory of something similar where in one rooms of the facility the children are kept in cages. There are also pigs in these cages (or one of the kids looks like a pig?). Does that match any of what you remember?

Comment: This is the exact book I’m trying to remember; I remember the children also being in care of a horrible nurse and when they OD’d from heavy sedation the children referred to it as “night night” I think the one with wings had a doll as well. I remember it so vividly but I know it’s not Miss Peregrines. Loosing my mind over this

Comment: @Vic Can we get you to post this as its own question, in case it turns out that Danielle is thinking of a different book? You can always link to this one, but provide all of the details you can in your question.

Answer (score 6):

[Angel Blood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2064140.Angel_Blood) by John Singleton

> The nurses call this place the Bin. We have to get out. We have to run
>   away before they hurt us for good. But there's no escaping Dr Dearly
>   and his brutality - is there? Four extraordinary children face a
>   terrifying ordeal. Their only hope is local hard-case Nail, but has he
>   got what it takes to save them? Brutal, tender and unforgettable,
>   Angel Blood creates its own extraordinary and brilliant world.

From [review on goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/387567416?book_show_action=true):

> Four kids (of unspecified age - they don't know how old they are) are
>   the only children left in a home (the Bin) for, well, unusual
>   children.[...]X-Ray has paper thin skin that
>   splits and bleeds easily, Chicken Angel has little wings like fingers
>   on her back, Lights Out has no eyes and Cough Cough has some sort of
>   lung disorder.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [“*Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children*”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Peregrine's_Home_for_Peculiar_Children)? It’s Wales rather than Scotland but otherwise matches many of your memories.

Teenage boy goes to Wales, meets girl, visits building with kids who have physical abnormalities (and/or x-men-type powers), watching films (though projected telepathically by one of the kids I think). They escape but in flight from enemies, not to escape the woman running the house.